# WSO2IS and CVE-2021-44228

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is WSO2IS impacted by [CVE-2021-44228](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44228) ?

If so, could we an update on https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/2021+Advisories (on what versions are affected, and what the recommend remediation is)?

Comment: This is something to pick-up with the WSO2 support (if you have a subscription). I assume they should post a security bulletin soon anyway as part of the communication of the security patches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure that you have "zip" and "unzip" commands installed on the server hosting the product.
2. Option 1: Navigate to the product-home folder and run the following command:

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wso2/security-tools/master/internal/update-scripts/CVE-2021-44228-mitigation.sh | bash`

Option 2: Or else download the script from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wso2/security-tools/master/internal/update-scripts/CVE-2021-44228-mitigation.sh`, copy the script into the product-home, and run the script from product-home, using the following command:

`bash CVE-2021-44228-mitigation.sh`

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Will this be published on the https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/2021+Advisories page?

Answer (score 1):

This is applicable to WSO2 Identity Server 5.9.0 and above versions only. There is a public announcement made by WSO2 on this.

https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=180948677

Answer (score 0):

What about the plugins/extensions using some wso2 libraries further using log4j2 core?
For example: org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.utils:jar:4.6.1 having pax logging as dependency which eventually has log4j 2.12.1 as provided dependency.

```
[INFO] +- org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.utils:jar:4.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wso2.orbit.org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60.0.wso2v1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.user.api:jar:4.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.base:jar:4.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap:jar:4.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.ops4j.pax.logging:pax-logging-api:jar:1.11.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- wrapper:wrapper:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging:pax-logging-api:jar:1.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.osgi:osgi.core:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.osgi:osgi.cmpn:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- **org.ops4j.pax.logging:pax-logging-log4j2:jar:1.11.3:compile**
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.ops4j.pax.logging:pax-logging-api:jar:1.11.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.osgi:osgi.core:jar:6.0.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.osgi:osgi.cmpn:jar:6.0.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

This is irrespective of wso2 IS version.